# Help to fix custom CDC Send function

Tags: microcontroller, usb, usb-device, lpc, nxp

I am using a custom code of CDC example from 177x_8x_PDL_110602 package (I am not using LPCOpen). 
I am having a trouble with CDC_Send function. That is the scenary: An python script send messages to LPC1788 serial USB, they are send time to time (200ms,300ms). The message is: "ping\x00", without quotes. When the LPC received the ping message it send back to PC this message: "resp 0\x00". After any time of messages interchange (perfectly), the LPC begins send the message wrong, like this: "r 0\x00", "sp 0\x00", "esp 0\x00", "r\x00", "\x00", ...

Bellow is the code that send the message:

```
void CDC_Send(const uint8_t *data, uint32_t data_size)
{
    // block until all bytes be sent
    while (ringbuff_size(g_tx_buffer) > 0);

    // puts the data into ring buffer
    ringbuff_write(g_tx_buffer, data, data_size);

    // forces the first send
    CDC_BulkIn();
}


void CDC_BulkIn(void)
{
    uint8_t buffer[USB_CDC_BUFSIZE];
    uint32_t bytes_to_write;

    if (!g_cdc_initialized) return;

    memset(buffer, 0, USB_CDC_BUFSIZE);

    bytes_to_write = ringbuff_read(g_tx_buffer, buffer, USB_CDC_BUFSIZE);

    if (bytes_to_write > 0)
    {
        USB_WriteEP(CDC_DEP_IN, buffer, bytes_to_write);
    }
}
```

The SetMode (command 0xF3) use the reset value (zero), so don't happen interrupts by NAK.
After a lot of time debuging I tried to put a delay after USB_WriteEP function, the delay value is 100us. In this way the messages interchange don't fail. So, I would like to fix this (remove the delay). Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Should you be pushing data to the USB hardware from your main program loop via your CDC_Send() function, vs only doing so when the USB actually polls you (which would presumably be in an interrupt context in your program)?

Comment: I forgot to say in the question body, I am using FreeRTOS. All CDC_Send calls are made by tasks. The messages isn't  sent  in interrupts.

Comment: Still, it looks like you are deciding when to send, and that's not how it is supposed to work - rather, you send data (if you have any available) when the USB host invites you to.  And that is, either literally or effectively, an interrupt condition (with regard to the processor, not with regard to so called USB interrupt endpoints)

Comment: Ok. But, why this interrupt condition interefe in the message that is being sent? After transfer the message to `LPC_USB->TxData` buffer, all work is from hardware side, right? And, a new message is pushed to `LPC_USB->TxData` buffer again when the previous buffer has been sent.

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug!

Rather than release the CDC_Send function to write a new message when the ring buffer is empty, I release it using one flag, that is setted in the last CDC_BulkIn interrupt, that is when the ring buffer is empty.

Bellow is the fixed code:

```
int g_send_ok;

void CDC_Init(void)
{
    // ...
    g_send_ok = 1;
}

void CDC_Send(const uint8_t *data, uint32_t data_size)
{
    // block until all bytes be sent
    while (!g_send_ok);
    g_send_ok = 0;

    // puts the data into ring buffer
    ringbuff_write(g_tx_buffer, data, data_size);

    // forces the first send
    CDC_BulkIn();
}


void CDC_BulkIn(void)
{
    uint8_t buffer[USB_CDC_BUFSIZE];
    uint32_t bytes_to_write;

    if (!g_cdc_initialized) return;

    memset(buffer, 0, USB_CDC_BUFSIZE);

    bytes_to_write = ringbuff_read(g_tx_buffer, buffer, USB_CDC_BUFSIZE);

    if (bytes_to_write > 0)
    {
        USB_WriteEP(CDC_DEP_IN, buffer, bytes_to_write);
    }
    else
    {
        g_send_ok = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a start - but you should probably be moving the send inside the interrupt context, and only setting flags outside to tell it if you do or don't have data that you want to send when that opportunity arrises.